# Printing a pattern in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I would like to print the following pattern using python:

```
00X
0X0
X00
```

Additionally, I have to print this using loops ONLY, without using arrays. Well, I have written an initial code, but is not scalable. Here is the initial code:

```
for i in range (1):
  for j in range (1):
    print(0, 0, "X")
for i in range (1):
  for j in range (1):
    print(0, "X", 0)
for i in range (1):
  for j in range (1):
    print("X", 0, 0)
```

I am looking for a suitable alternative. Please also feel free to contribute on the [source code on my GitHub: https://github.com/micahondiwa/python/blob/main/0x00-python/31-pattern.py.

Thank you.

I tried using the for a loop. Although I got the output, the result is not scalable. I am expecting to find a solution that uses a function to implement a loop and print the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nested loop will work. The outer loop goes from `n-1` to `0` and the inner loop goes from `0` to `n-1`. When the outer and inner loop variables are equal, print an `X`.

```
def f(n):
    for row in range(n-1, -1, -1):
        for col in range(n):
            if row == col:
                print('X', end='')
            else:
                print('0', end='')
        print()
```

Example run:

```
>>> f(5)
0000X
000X0
00X00
0X000
X0000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single loop:

```
SQUARE_SIZE = 8

for i in range(SQUARE_SIZE):
    print("0"*(SQUARE_SIZE-i-1) + "X" + "0"*i)
```

Output:

```
0000000X
000000X0
00000X00
0000X000
000X0000
00X00000
0X000000
X0000000
```

Comment: Is this not an array implementation?

Comment: Well technically strings are arrays but it's something you cannot get around in Python since it doesn't have a character type.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you want to write a matrix, where there is X in the secondary diagonal and 0 in all other places, and you can't use arrays (which you don't need).

If I am correct, you basically want to do this (if we say the matrix is 10x10):

- In the first row you want to write 9 zeros and 1 x
- In the second row you want to write 8 zeros, 1 x, and 1 zero
- In the third row you want to write 7 zeros, 1x, and 2 zeros
  ...

This shows the next pattern

- In the first row (10-1) zeros and 1 x
- In the second row (10-2) zeros, 1 x and 1 zero
- In the third row (10-3) zeros, 1 x and 2 zeros
  ...
  Now we see that we write (n-i-1) zeros, 1 x, and i zeros

So we can do it like this:

```
n = 10
for i in range(n):
    print('0' * (n-i-1) + 'X' + '0' * i)
```

EDIT:

Since @micahondiwa said it needs to be implemented in function, here is the code sample:

```
def my_func(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print('0' * (n-i-1) + 'X' + '0' * i)
```

Comment: Thank you @Nedim. Your explanation is correct, and your solution is also correct. However, I am looking for a function to implement it.

Comment: In that case, just insert the code from the sample in the function
def my_func(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print('0' * (n-i-1) + 'X' + '0' * i)

Answer (score 1):

Here `n` is the number of *rows* and *columns*.

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if(j == n - 1 - i):
            print("X", end="")
        else:    
            print("0", end="")
    print()
```

**output:**

```
n = 3
>>> 00X
>>> 0X0
>>> X00
```